# Finding repetitions in sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list:

```
listaBase1 = {2, 1, 25, 6, 14, 4, 9, 19, 5, 23, 18, 10, 17, 12, 3, 20}
```

And I created sublists from this:

```
G1 = Subsets[listaBase1, {15}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 6 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 25 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 1 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  2 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
>  1 & 25 & 6 & 14 & 4 & 9 & 19 & 5 & 23 & 18 & 10 & 17 & 12 & 3 & 20 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

And now I have another list:

```
listaBase2 = {1,25,23,2,14,3,5,7,8,11,13,15,16,21,22,24}
```

With another sublists:

```
G2 = Subsets[listaBase2, {15}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 23 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 25 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  1 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
>  25 & 23 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 16 & 21 & 22 & 24 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

How do I know if there is any repetition in these two groups $G1$ and $G2$? And if there is a repetition, is there a way to show which list would be?

Comment: What exactly is a "repetition" here? Are you looking for a list that is common to both `G1` and `G2`? (You can use `Intersection[]` for that.)

Comment: @J. M. If there are any of these 32 lists that are repeated.

Comment: Have you seen `Gather[]`, then?

Comment: Ok. I will see this.

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: @corey979 The order is not important.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, you can `Sort` each sublist in both lists, and then find the `Intersection`: `Intersection[Sort /@ G1, Sort /@ G2]` yields `{}`, meaning there are no repetitions. If there were any, the output would be the list of **sorted** sublists that are in both `G1` and `G2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of the sublists doesn't matter, simply

```
Intersection[Sort /@ G1, Sort /@ G2]
```

> {}

If the order of (one) of the repeating sublists is to be preserved, then there's [`ContainsAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsAll.html?q=ContainsAll):

```
f[a_, b_] := 
 DeleteCases[#, {}, Infinity] & @ Flatten[#, 1] & @
  Table[ If[ContainsAll[a[[i]], b[[j]]], a[[i]], Nothing], 
    {i, 1, Length@a}, {j, 1, Length@b}]
```

which on `G1` and `G2` gives `{}`.

---

A smaller case:

```
a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b1 = {2, 3, 4, 5};
a = Subsets[a1, {3}];
b = RandomSample /@ Subsets[b1, {3}];

f[a, b]
```

> {{2, 3, 4}}

and

```
f[b, a]
```

> {{3, 4, 2}}

Answer (score 0):

```
G1=Sort/@G1;
G2=Sort/@G2;
```

Will get rid of order differences for entries in group elements, if that is useful to you.

```
its=Intersection[G1,G2]
```

Will be non-empty if there is at least one entry shared by G1 and G2 (and will contain them). Afterwards you can add to this list by searching for repetitions i.e. in G1 only

```
Do[
    If[G1[[i]]===G1[[j]],AppendTo[its,G1[[i]]];];
,{i,1,Length[G1]-1},{j,i+1,Length[G1]}]
its
```

And similarly for G2.

If you are only interested to find repetitions within G1 separately (or G2 separately), run `its={}` before the do-loop above and ignore the intersection command.

Also, i.e.

```
Length[G1]-Length[DeleteDuplicates[G1]]
```

Will tell you just how many identical entries there are in G1 (similarly for G2).

Comment: That is not true; consider `Intersection[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 4}}]` and the OP [said that the order isn't important](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134626/finding-repetitions-in-sublists#comment363280_134626), so `{1,2}` and `{2,1}` are repetitions. As for the `Do`: `DeleteDuplicates` and `Complement` is sufficient.

Comment: I believe the OP meant that the order of subsets is irrelevant, not the order of each entry in each sublist. I will add a sorting to avoid complications with that.

Comment: Added the optional sorting.

Comment: Don't have mathematica in front of me right now to test, but i think that there might be a non-zero chance that i.e. `Complement[{a,a},{a}]` actually returns `{}`. Thats why I went with the adhoc failproof solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more compact way to implement the previous suggestions:

```
G3 = Sort /@ Join[G1, G2];
Replace[Last@
  Reap[Length@Position[G3, #] > 1 && Sow@# & /@ G3], {v : {___}} :> v]
```

And then just to check that it works we'll try it on a dataset with only overlaps:

```
G3 = Sort /@ Join[G1, G1];
Length@Replace[
  Last@Reap[
    Length@Position[G3, #] > 1 && Sow@# & /@ G3], {v : {___}} :> v]
```